# How can I type text from a file on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, quicksilver, textexpander

I have text in `~/myfile.txt` and I'd like to be able to "type" it into the current application, which will probably be `TextMate` or `Terminal`

I'd like to see if I can have this happen without using the clipboard. Quicksilver has a cool action called "Type Text", but it works with the current selection and doesn't pull the text from a file:

[image]

I tried using Quicksilver's "save command to file" option, which would save this as "Type My Text.qscommand", which I could then modify on the fly and replace the "text" that was inside of this file, and my thinking was to have that run which would type the text, but apparently even without modifying the file this command does not work if it is saved to a file and executed.

[image]

So my other thoughts - possibly use

- Typinator
- Textexpander
- Applescript
- maybe some other macro program?

to set up a way that I can type text from a file (`~/myfile.txt`) into the current application, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Try Alfred instead of Quicksilver! Has a nicer UI and better search ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that works if your text is only one line : Select your text file in the first pane, right arrow in it, then choose Paste from the action pane.

I think you need the Text Manipulation plugin to be able to right-arrow into text files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Automator. Select to create a *Service* that receives *no input* in *any application* whose *Output replaces selected text* (you don't actually need a text selection for this to work).

- Add a *Get Specified Finder Items* action, and add `myfile.txt` to its list. You could alternatively hardcode the file path below and skip this step.
- Then, add a *Run Shell Script* action, and pass input *as arguments*. Replace the default `echo` command by `cat`.

This will cause the file contents to be the output of your service, which will be added to the current document you're editing.

[image]

---

**TextMate** works as expected.

**Terminal** ignores a single trailing newline when inserting the text, i.e. you need two if you want to directly execute the last line as a command.

Comment: cool. will give it a try. btw are you a quicksilver user?

Comment: @cwd launchbar, since quicksilver messed up its index once too often. I use it for nothing fancy though, just launching, spotlight and calculator.

Comment: maybe give it another try since they have a new version and you're a power user...

Comment: @cwd Did it work for you?

Comment: still exploring. don't worry i will get around to accepting it :)

Comment: @cwd Was just wondering since there's no other answers and no feedback from you. You're usually pretty quick in responding and/or accepting.